# Is using 'What' in a short answer of 'Identifying' something correct?

Tags: pronouns

When I was kid, I used to watch a lot of quiz shows. In some shows, I remember that the teams used **to answer** the asker using the word 'what'.

For example, the round is of identifying the term and the asker asks this question to the team A.

`A process used by plants and other organisms to convert light energy, normally from the sun, into chemical energy that can be later released to fuel the organisms' activities.`

One of the girls in Team A starts thinking and answers...

> Hmmm.... **what is** photosynthesis *(with no tone of questioning something).*

And the quiz master says...

> *"What...is....photosynthesis....(smiles and cheers)...Team A, you got it right and now have leading score in this round.*

**The question** -

Is using 'what' while answering the question of 'what it is' correct?

Comment: That was the quiz show *Jeopardy* which differentiated itself from other quiz shows by providing the *answer* and having the contestants guess the *question*.  Of course I always thought it was a bit absurd because nobody would actually provide the *answer* they gave if *the question* were actually asked.

Comment: @Jim No no...it was probably a local quiz show (Indian) - Britannica Quiz Show hosted by Derek O'Brien.

Comment: Well, then it was probably a local copy of *Jeopardy*

Comment: @Jim It wasn't. Because that was *one of the ways* the teams answered. It was quite a normal quiz. My concern is *Is that format correct, the way I described?* That way, they'd show a picture of some place and would ask 'Identify the place' and the answer would go - **"What is Hagia Sophia (?)**

Comment: It's only correct if the format was to provide the answer in the form of a question.  Otherwise, it is not typically the case that answers are phrased as questions.  Obviously it was correct for that show because if it wasn't they would have lost instead of gained points.

Comment: Is it somewhat close to... *HHmm... what (I call) is...photosynthesis?*

Comment: I would say it isn't.

Comment: It sounds like the game is to guess the question of the given answer. So it might be fine to think of it as a quoted question, *"Hmmm... [it's] 'What is photosynthesis?'"*. Also, *wh*-questions usually don't end in rising tone.

Comment: @Jim and DamkerngT got it exactly right. Note that the quoted "question" that is "asked" is not a question but a statement. The contestants are clearly familiar with the *Jeopardy* format and understand that a Question in the form of an Answer calls for an Answer in the form of a Question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the format of a game show and not likely to aid someone who is learning the English language.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung it appears to you but it is not! If you have read the question, it asks about the sentence structure beginning with 'what' and is not the question. Which line of question did you find asking 'game'  or its format? And I am aware of off topics here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'question' in your example is not a question at all.  It is a statement that describes the process of 'photosynthesis.'  When presented with such a statement in a quiz show, it's possible (or even likely) that the appropriate form of answer would be the question with which the girl from Team A responded.

Otherwise, no, it is not a normal speech pattern to answer a question with 'what' or 'what is', unless you are attempting to allude to a game that requires answers in the form of questions (including Jeopardy.)

For a contrived example:  If someone approached you on the street and said "a small, furry animal with sharp claws that people often keep as pets," you would probably be confused as to their intent.  Unless the person was obviously attempting to get you to help them by telling them the word for 'cat,' that exchange would be highly unlikely to occur. That being said, if they **were** trying to elicit the word 'cat,' one would most likely respond with "Do you mean 'cat?'" and not "What is a cat?"

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

It is generally **not** correct to identify something by using “what” or any other question word unless you are either participating in or making reference to a game show.

---

### Background

Though it neither was the first nor is the only quiz show to use this format, this switching of question and answer is familiar to many as a rule for playing *Jeopardy!*

The switch is explained in the [section of the show's Wikipedia page devoted to the show's conception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!#Conception):

> My wife Julann just came up with the idea one day when we were in a plane bringing us back to New York from Duluth. I was mulling over game show ideas, when she noted that there had not been a successful "question and answer" game on the air since the quiz show scandals. Why not do a switch, and **give the answers to the contestant and let them come up with the question?** She fired a couple of answers to me: "5,280" – and the question of course was "How many feet in a mile?". Another was "79 Wistful Vista"; that was Fibber and Mollie McGee's address. I loved the idea, went straight to NBC with the idea, and they bought it without even looking at a pilot show.
> <sub>—  Merv Griffin, on the origins of *Jeopardy!*</sub>

---

### Key Distinction

The contestants’ responses are, in fact, questions—correctly formed according to all the grammar that would normally correspond to requests for information—but instead of being *used* as questions, they are being *mentioned* as the answer. In writing, we avoid use/mention confusion by using quotation marks or recognizable formatting to distinguish words that we want to mention (or talk about, for example) rather than use in a normal way as part of the sentence:

> **Use**
>   Cheese is derived from milk.
>
> **Mention**
>   "Cheese" is derived from the Old English word "cyse".
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia article - “Use–mention distinction”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)</sub>

In speech, on the other hand, we have several options, including verbal emphasis and [hand gesture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quotes)s. In cases like the one you mention, clarity between use and mention of these questions-as-answers is aided by the break (which you noticed) from the usual practice of marking questions with a rise in pitch (↗) as the end of the sentence is reached:

> **Normal Question**
>   
>  Who is Philip Seymour ↗ Hoffman?
>
> **Game Show Answer**
>  “Who is Philip Seymour ↘ Hoffman?”

The latter is not intended as a question, as you rightly observe. It is, however, phrased as a question, because it is being submitted whole as the question (that is, the identification) the contestant believes corresponds with the answer (that is, the description) that has been given by the host.

---

### Caveats

#### 1

One *could* encounter this in daily life. A possible scenario would be that one is attending a lecture and the person at the front of the room poses a question to everyone. One member of the audience might turn to the other and ask “What did he ask?”. The correct answer in that case would be to quote the question, whereupon someone responding would avoid typical question intonation to clarify that they are not themselves asking the question or seeking its answer.

#### 2

Though it is not the same sort of thing as your example, it's also possible to answer questions by restating them in part:

> **X:** What is the deal with Z?
>  **Y:** What it is is that she's tired of being last all the time!
> **Z:** Yes, that's what it is.

In this case, Y's mention of “what it is” uses those words as a replacement for “the deal with Z” (that is, the issue Z appears to be facing). Z's confirmation of Y's assertion uses the words “what it is” in the same way, but places them at the end of the statement. Both Y and Z are emphasizing identification of the issue, but the word “what” is more or less superfluous in this and related cases.

Comment: Brilliant and thorough answer.